# Why is there a traceback and indexerror in my code?

Tags: python

Currently I am learning Python from the book 'The Coders Apprentice' and I have stumbled upon an exercise which I have the feeling that I have nearly solved, but I get an error when I execute the program.

This is the exercise:

> Write a program that takes a string and produces a new string that contains the exact characters that the first string contains, but in order of their ASCII-codes.
>   For instance, the string "Hello, world!" should be turned into " !,Hdellloorw". This is
>   relatively easy to do with list functions, which will be introduced in a future chapter, but for now try to do it with string manipulation functions alone.

I have added the code below and the error message as a picture.

```
from pcinput import getString

entString=getString("Enter your string here: ")
yourString=entString.strip()


def positioner(oldPosition):
    newPosition=0
    x=0
    while x<len(yourString):
        if ord(yourString[oldPosition])>ord(yourString[x]):
            newPosition+=1
        x+=1
    return newPosition

i=0
y=0
newString=""

while y<len(yourString):
    if positioner(i)==y:
        newString+=yourString[i]
        y+=1
    elif positioner(i)<y:
        newString+=yourString[i]
    if i<len(yourString):
        i+=1
    else:
        i=0

print(newString)
```

What have I done wrong? I am new to programming.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure we can see your error message picture. It might be easier to just paste the message in below your code.

Comment: This is an ideal opportunity for debugging. Using a very short string (e.g. "the"), print out your intermediate variables, and then write out the results you were expecting on paper. The discrepancy between what you expected and what you got will help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: (This may close in its current state, because the error you mentioned is missing from the post, and that is probably critical. If you can add that, it can be reopened again. Add it as promptly as you can, to help avoid closure).

Comment: Is the pcstring module included in your distribution? I ran your code in python 3.6.8 on an Ubuntu system and received an error as that module is not available.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an index error because the line `if positioner(i)==y:` is being called with a value of `i` equal to the length of `yourString`.  `yourString[oldPosition]` is then accessing an index which doesn't exist.

This is happening because the loop condition (`y<len(yourString)`) isn't doing any checking on the value of `i`, which is the one causing problems.

Some other quick comments:

- You can use `yourString = input("Enter your string here: ")` to replace the first four lines, as I'm not sure what `pcinput` is - and couldn't find any packages of the same name.
- Instead of using the `while/x+=1` construct, you could instead use a `for x in range(len(yourString))`, which is a little neater.